# Piano Chords on White Keys

Tags: code-golf, music

## Backstory [which is not true]

A piano is set up like this:

[image: ![http://www.piano-lessons-made-simple.com/images/2-Octave-Labled.gif]

However, on my piano, all of the black keys are broken!

I still want to be able to play some chords on my broken piano though.

In music, a chord is a group of notes that are played together. To allow for input of chords, I will first define what a semitone is.

#### What is a semitone?

A semitone is the smallest distance in Western music. If you look at the top part of the piano, you see that you can usually move from a black key to a white key, or vice versa; however, between `B` and `C` and `E` and `F` there is no black key.

#### What is a chord?

For the purposes of this challenge, we define a chord as a bunch of notes with a certain number of semitones between them. For example, let's take a took at a `4-3-3` chord starting on `C` (for music people, this is a V<sup>7</sup> chord in F major). We start at `C`. We count up 4 semitones: `C#`, `D`, `D#`, `E`. The next note is `E`, and we count 3 semitones up after that: `F`, `F#`, `G`. The next note is `G`, and we count 3 semitones up after that: `G#`, `A`, `Bb`. So, we get `C-E-G-Bb`. Yay! But wait... `Bb` is a black key and those are broken... However, if we start from `G`, we get `G-B-D-F`! Yay!

#### Input

Input is given as a list of integers in any reasonable format. This represents the chord as described above.

#### Output

Output should be a list of notes on which I can start to only need to use white keys. This can also just be a string of all of the up to 7 notes because all of the keynames will be one character. You must be able to handle having an empty output as well.

## Test Cases

```
input -> output // comments
4 3 -> C F G // this is a major triad
3 4 -> D E A // this is a minor triad
4 3 3 -> G // this is the major-minor seventh chord
3 3 3 -> [empty output] // this is the diminished-diminished seventh chord. All of them use black keys
4 4 -> [empty output] // this is an augmented triad
3 3 -> B // this is a diminished triad
1 -> B E // this is just a minor second
11 -> C F // this is just a major seventh
```

## Other specs

- Standard Loopholes forbidden
- You may assume that the input has at least one integer
- You may assume that all of the integers are non-negative and less than 12 (because the piano repeats every 12 notes)
- Output may be in any order

## Winning Criteria

The shortest valid submission as of April 15th will be accepted.

Comment: We may assume "non-negative and less than 12" - should that not be "positive and less than or equal to 12"?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Fundamentally there is no difference; my method allows for a Perfect Unison but not a Perfect Octave; yours vice-versa. Theoretically, your restriction might make more sense but I think I probably shouldn't change it because there are already answers and it doesn't change the challenge fundamentally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
236ḃ2ṙÐ€7+\€Ṭ
+\ịþ¢Ạ€TịØA
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@29kbPZwR7PRw50zD0941LTGXDsGSD7cuYZLO@bh7u7D@w4terhrAVAoBMSb4fj///9oEx3jWAA)** or see a [test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@29kbPZwR7PRw50zD0941LTGXDsGSD7cuYZLO@bh7u7D@w4terhrAVAoBMSb4fj/6J7D7UBuFhA/apija/eoYW7k///R0SY6xrE60cY6JkASyIbyILQJWBTCNgRhw9hYAA)

#### How?

```
236ḃ2ṙÐ€7+\€Ṭ - Link 1, white-note-offsets: no arguments
236ḃ2         - 236 in bijective base 2 [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2] - semitones G->A, A->B ...
     ṙÐ€7     - rotate left by, mapped over [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] - i.e. as above for each
                    starting white key (1st one A->B,B->C,...; 2nd B->C,C->D,...; etc)
         +\€  - reduce €ach with addition - i.e. absolute number of semitones: [[2,3,5,7,8,10,12],[1,3,5,6,8,10,12],[2,4,5,7,9,11,12],[2,3,5,7,9,10,12],[1,3,5,7,8,10,12],[2,4,6,7,9,11,12],[2,4,5,7,9,10,12]]
            Ṭ - untruth (vectorises) - make lists with 1s at those indexes: [[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]]

+\ịþ¢Ạ€TịØA - Main link: list of semitone gap integers (even negatives will work)
+\          - reduce by addition - gets the absolute semitone offsets needed
    ¢       - last link (1) as a nilad
   þ        - outer product with:
  ị         -     index into - 7 lists, each with 1s for white and 0s for black keys hit
                      note that indexing is modular and all the lists are length 12
                      so any integer is a valid absolute offset, not just 0-11 inclusive
     Ạ€     - all truthy for €ach - for each get a 1 if all keys are white ones, else 0
       T    - truthy indexes - get the valid starting white keys as numbers from 1 to 7
        ị   - index into:
         ØA -     the uppercase alphabet
```

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 31 bytes

*Thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) for a correction.*

```
'BAGFEDC'"GYs12X\110BQX@YSYsm?@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@6/u5Oju5urirK7kHllsaBQRY2ho4BQY4RAZHFmca@/w/3@0iYKhgYJJLAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#U3JIj/Cq@K/u5Oju5urirK7kFVlsaBQRY2ho4BQY4RAZHFmca@/wPzZWXVdX/X91tImCcaxCtLGCCZAEsqE8CG0CFoWwDUHYMLYWAA).

#### Explanation

The pattern `2 2 1 2 2 2 1` specifies the intervals between consecutive white keys. The program uses a loop that applies all cyclic shifts to this basic pattern, in order to test each key as a potential lowest note of the input chord. For each shift, the cumulative sum of the pattern is obtained. For example, for `B` as potential lowest note, the pattern has been shifted to `1 2 2 1 2 2 2` and its cumulative sum is `1 3 5 6 8 10 12`.

Now, to see if this can support a `4 3 3` chord we compute the cumulative sum of the chord intervals, which is `4 7 10`; reduce it via 1-based modulo 12 (an interval of `14` would give `2`); and check if those numbers are all members of the allowed values `1 3 5 6 8 10 12`. That's not the case in this example. Had it been the case, we would output the letter `B`.

The correspondence between cyclic shifts and output letters is defined by the string `'BAGFEDC'`. This indicates that `'B'` (first character) corresponds to a cyclic shift by `1`; `'A'` (second character) corresponds to a cyclic shift by `2` etc.

```
'BAGFEDC'  % Push this string
"          % For each character from the string
  G        %   Push input array
  Ys       %   Cumulative sum
  12X\     %   1-based modulo 12, element-wise (1,12,13,14 respectively give 1,12,1,2)
  110BQ    %   Push 110, convert to binary, add 1 element-wise: gives [2 2 1 2 2 2 1]
  X@       %   Push current iteration index, starting at 1
  YS       %   Cyclic shift to the right by that amount
  Ys       %   Cumulative sum
  m        %   Ismember. Gives an array of true of false entries
  ?        %   If all true
    @      %     Push current character
           %   End (implicit)
           % End (implicit)
           % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 110 bytes (ISO 8859-1 encoding)

```mathematica
±i_:=#&@@@Select["A#BC#D#EF#G#"~StringTake~{Mod[#,12,1]}&/@#&/@(Accumulate[i~Prepend~#]&/@Range@12),FreeQ@"#"]
```

Defines a unary function `±` taking a list of integers as input (no restrictions on the size or signs of the integers, actually) and returns a list of one-character strings. For example, `±{3,4}` returns `{"A","D","E"}`.

`"A#BC#D#EF#G#"~StringTake~{Mod[#,12,1]}&/@#` is a function that turns a list of integers into the corresponding note names, except that `#` stands for any black key. This is applied to each element of `Accumulate[i~Prepend~#]&/@Range@12`, which builds up a list of note values from the list input list of note intervals, starting with each possible note from 1 to 12. We filter out all such note-name lists that contain `"#"` using `Select[...,FreeQ@"#"]`, and then return the first note in each remaining list using `#&@@@`.

Comment: Nice submission!

Comment: Question: Does Mathematica use its own byte system? This is 110 characters but in UTF-8 it's 111 bytes because of the `+/-` symbol.

Comment: You can completely strip the assignment and just "implicitly return" a function.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: I found I had to name the variable in `Accumulate[i~Prepend~#]&` because otherwise there'd be a currying clash. Feel free to find a workaround though!

Comment: @HyperNeutrino: you're right that UTF-8 is the standard encoding, but Mathematica can (usually) function in ISO 8859-1 encoding as well. I've noted that in the post.

Comment: Alright. Thanks, I just needed clarification that the bytecount was correct.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>159</s> 155 bytes

(Posting this after making sure there's a valid submission that's shorter than this one)

```python
import numpy
s='C.D.EF.G.A.B'
def k(y):return lambda x:s[(x+y)%12]
for i in range(12):
    if s[i]!='.'and'.'not in map(k(i),numpy.cumsum(input())):print s[i]
```

Pretty much just the trivial solution. Inputs as a list of integers and outputs with each character on an individual line.

-4 bytes by removing an unnecessary variable

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>72</s> <s>71</s> 68 bytes

```
a=>[..."C1D1EF1G1A1B"].filter((c,i,b)=>!+c>a.some(e=>+b[i+=e,i%12]))
```

Loops through each key omitting black keys, then checking that the cumulative sum of semitones never lands on a black key.

Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Arnauld.

Comment: Readability?! Are you sure you're on the right site? :-)